# You cannot access JIRA at present. Look at the table below to identify the reasons

Tags: maven, plugins, jira

I've run the atlas-run where my pom.xml is situated ,and after that when i tried to see the result in the browser , i found this error :
  [image]

what can i do to solve it ?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you are using java 7, 
if yes ,try java 6